# SQL Substring Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have a column called mix which is as follows

```
120
102 201
300
234 212
11 21
```

So the issue is I want to extract the digits of the left when a space is found, I am trying that with substring as shown below, I wonder why it is not working.

```
 select mix,  
 SUBSTRING(mix,1,CHARINDEX(' ',mix)-1)
 FROM tbl_xx
 where CHARINDEX(mix,' ')>0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find string comes first in `CHARINDEX`... Change it in WHERE condition

```
SELECT mix, SUBSTRING(mix, 1, CHARINDEX(' ',mix) - 1)
FROM   tbl_xx
WHERE  CHARINDEX(' ', mix) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select mix,  
 SUBSTRING(mix,1,CHARINDEX(' ',mix)-1)
 FROM tbl_xx
 where CHARINDEX(' ',mix)>0
```

Your where clause charindex is wrong check the above

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT`

```
select mix,LEFT(mix,CHARINDEX(' ',mix)-1)
 FROM tabl
 where CHARINDEX(' ',mix)>0
```