# How to trim a string from a space

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a field like

```
BestStreet 123/56
```

and I want to get

```
BestStreet
```

I've tried:

```
LEFT(sd.UliceCP, CHARINDEX(' ', sd.UliceCP)-1)
```

Comment: And why doesn't your code work?  It should work on the example you have given.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Substring Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879450/sql-substring-issue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want to add a space, just in case one does not exist.

**For example:  Notice the `sd.UliceCP+' '`**

```
LEFT(sd.UliceCP, CHARINDEX(' ', sd.UliceCP+' ')-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Substring Also we can get the same

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(sd.UliceCP,0,CHARINDEX(' ',sd.UliceCP))
```